# Подключение статики в Django

Tags: python, django

Добрый день, всем. Помогите подключить статику в django

Код setting.py

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = 'c:/Python27/Scripts/todo/media/'

    # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
    # trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
    # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
    # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
    # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = 'c:/Python27/Scripts/todo/collected_static/'

    # URL prefix for static files.
    # Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Additional locations of static files
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        'c:/Python27/Scripts/todo/static/'
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.)
```

Comment: base.html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" media="all" type = "text/css">

Comment: что нужно добавить url.py

Answer (score 1):

чудненько, это зачем media в папке с Python хранить?

Вот с рабочего проекта пример:

сначала сверху задаем:

```
import os

PROJ_MODULE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(PROJ_MODULE_ROOT, ".."))
root_path = lambda *args: os.path.join(ROOT, *args)
path = lambda *args: os.path.join(PROJ_MODULE_ROOT, *args)
```

потом:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = root_path('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = path('../../static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то Вам понасоветовали странного тут.

Возможно, Вы не прописали 'django.core.context_processors.static' в TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS в settings.py, и поэтому {{ STATIC_URL }} у Вас просто не заполняется.

Answer (score 0):

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))    
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')   


STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]